# Design collapsed when position changes from absolute to relative

Tags: html, css

See my case is, i have to center a `div` [DivFirst] inside another `div` [DivSecond].

 and i had done it by setting the following `css` given below,

```
#DivFirst
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}
#DivSecond
{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    margin-left:-100px; 
}
```

after that, for a reason i had changed the `DivSecond's position from absolute to relative`,
 
as a result the `design` got collapsed, that is, the `DivFirst's height` got changed and the 
inner div [`DivSecond`] was not `centered` properly.

I can go with the `position absolute` for the `inner div`, but i just need to know why this is
happening.? by the way if i am doing anything wrongly, kindly direct me in the right path.

---

[**Note:** *Run the demo by setting both absolute and relative position for the inner div*]

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VvjBD/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the negative top margin is pulling #DivFirst with it.  You can stop this behavior by adding overflow: auto to #DivFirst.

Since you know the size of the divs involved you may want to consider just manually positioning them without trying to nudge them into place with negative margins http://jsfiddle.net/DDcfD/ :

CSS:

```
#DivFirst
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
}

#DivSecond
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:150px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: "negative top margin is pulling #DivFirst with it." if i set left and top as 0 then your point might be helped me, but i had set the both as 50%. can u explain this with a good point? :)

Comment: This is a case of collapsing margins.  Since there is nothing separating the two elements, their margins collapse and they both take on the value of the margin with the greatest absolute magnitude.  You can avoid this by adding a border, padding, or clearing the float context (overflow: auto; will work) in the parent.  For more information you can read about collapsing margins here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing or here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0):

That happens, because when you give `#DivSecond` `position: absolute;`, you position your target element relatively to its first positioned ancestor element, as long as it is not static positioned.

When you give your `#DivSecond` `position` property a `relative` value, you no longer position it relatively to it's ancestor element, but relatively to it's normal position, where it would be by default, which in your case means, you add 50% to the `left` and 'top' of it's normal position.

You can see examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).